# What topics to include on a first course in number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory, education, applications

I need to teach a course in elementary number theory next academic year. What topics should be included on a first course in this area? What is best order of doing things?  The students have a minimum background in proof but this is a second year undergraduate module.
I am looking for applications which will motivate the student in this subject. 
Are there good resources on elementary number theory?

Comment: Continued fractions and their application to music could be an interesting one (just as an example)

Comment: Induction, congruence classes/linear congruences, Chinese remainder theorem, Euler's Theorem, some sets/functions, groups/permutations, group theory (like langrange's theorem)

Comment: I find this question odd as usually courses at undergraduate level are determined according to the students' assumed interests and the departament's goals: are these mathematics students? Is the department strong in number theory? Has this first course to serve as a basis for continuation in algebraic number theory and/or close subjects or must it stand by itself and be only a "gentle" introduction to the subject...?

Comment: The goal is to highlight rigour but not to put off students. There is no continuation course and I think your description of a gentle introduction is a true reflection of what we want to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

The best thing would be to follow David M. Burton's book 'Elementary Number Theory'.

Answer (score 3):

You could do much worse than to use Underwood Dudley, [*Elementary Number Theory*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/048646931X); it’s $35$ years old, but it’s very readable, it has all of the traditional topics, and it’s available in an inexpensive Dover paperback edition and an even more inexpensive Kindle edition.

Comment: i am studying number theory from David Burton's book elementary analysis and second chapter on primes, in that exercise i had no idea how to start attempting questions on primes.   First chapter was ok though. Am i doing something wrong here ?  This is first time i am doing number theory by myself. or should i look for some other book ?
Thanks

Comment: @Olivia: I’m not familiar with Burton’s book, I’m afraid, so I can’t really judge, though it is certainly possible that looking at another treatment of the same material would help. I’ve been retired now for 12 years and am no longer at all familiar with what’s readily available, but I did find a couple of elementary number theory texts freely available online, by [Karl-Dieter Crisman](https://math.gordon.edu/ntic/) and by [W. Edwin Clark](http://shell.cas.usf.edu/~wclark/#ELEMENTARY_NUMBER_THEORY), though I’ve taken a close look and can’t say how good they are.

Comment: ok thanks i will look

Comment: @Olivia: You’re welcome; I hope that you can find something helpful.

Comment: yes i also found underwood dudley to be nice, and one gerath jones